# How to compare two fields in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, slider, compare, meteor

I have a problem with meteor, well I display some groups with a slider. When you click on a group I display some users.

I want display only the users belong to the group Admin, in the group admin and only the users manager on the groups manager etc...

HTML :

```
<template name="manage">
    {{> header}}

    <div class="menu">
       <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-group">
          {{#each roles}}
<div class="accordion-heading country">
            <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/100x30" alt="country flag" style="float:left; margin: 3px 10px 0 3px; text-align:center;"/> -->
            <p style="border: 1px solid grey; border-radius: 5px; font-weight: bold; width: 100px; height :30px; float:left; margin: 3px 10px 0 3px; text-align:center;">{{name}}</p>
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#country{{_id}}">{{pays}} - {{lieu}} - {{increment}}</a>
    </div>
    <div id="country{{_id}}" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Utilisateurs</th>
              <th>Nom</th>
              <th>Prenom</th>
              <th>Statut</th>
              <th>ID</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>   
          <tbody>
          {{#each users "1"}}
          <!-- {{#if roles "lol"}} -->
            <tr>
              {{#each emails}}
              <td>{{address}}</td>
              {{/each}}
              <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
              <td>{{profile.name}}</td>
              <td>OK</td>
              <td>{{increment}}</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- {{/if}} -->
          {{/each}}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div> 
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
Template.manage.roles = function () {
    return Meteor.roles.find();
};


Template.manage.users = function (inc) {
   return Meteor.users.find({increment : inc});
};
```

So, I'm trying to compare two fields in DB but have you a better solution ?
Sorry, I'm new with meteor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to go about it, would be to store the selected group in a session and then have your Meteor.users.find() react to the session variable.
Session in meteor is inherently reactive.

Example:

```
<template name="manage">
  <button class="role" value="manager">Manager</button>
  {{#each users}}
    {{name}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.manage.events({
  'click .role': function(event, template) {
    Session.set('role', event.target.value);
  }
});

Template.manage.helpers({
  users: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find({role: Session.get('role')});
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice !!! Thanks a lot ! it's work ! But can I retrieve a value from a <a> ? Because <button> cause a bug :)

Comment: you can retrieve a value from between <a> tags if you use event.target.innerHTML, otherwise you can also use event.target.getAttribute('value')